# Using SDL with Win32 Window

Tags: c, winapi, sdl

I'm using gcc in Codeblocks for my c programming on Windows Xp.

When learning c I created a basic program that takes a book text file and counts the letter frequency.

A couple of months later when learning SDL basics i thought it would be a good idea to
create a bar graph to display the results of the c program.

I now have 2 working programs BUT with no idea of how to combine them.

Searching the net has produced numerous mentions of a Windows hack that allows SDL
to be displayed inside a Win32 window, but i've been unable to find an actual code routine.

I know at some point I will have to learn Windows programming, but was hoping i could find a short, quick fix meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my approach and coded a pure SDL program.